# Backbone.js trigger function each time Router is used

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Just wondering if there is a simple way to trigger a custom function each time a Backbone.js router is utilized, without having to add it in each of the router functions. Now my script looks like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '' : 'index',
        'test': 'test',
    },

    initialize: function() {
    },

    index: function() {
        customFunction();
        indexView.render();
    },

    test: function() {
        customFunction();
        testView.render();
    },

});
```

I would like to have it something like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '' : 'index',
        'test': 'test',
    },

    initialize: function() {
    },

    index: function() {
        indexView.render();
    },

    test: function() {
        testView.render();
    },

    change: function() { 
        customFunction();
    }

});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whenever a route is matched by the `Router`, a `route:[name]` event is fired with the name of the route matched, to allow classes to listen to certain route matches.  All backbone objects also support the `all` event which fires whenever an event does.

So you could make use of this to bind to the `all` event on the `Router`, which will fire whenever the router does some routing.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bind( "all", this.change )
},
```

If you were interested in the route that matched, it is passed as the first parameter to the bound function.

More details [here in the FAQ](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Although, I had to use this.bind() instead of just bind()

Comment: Does the event occur before or after the route is "run" if you've got `{trigger: true}` as part of your `.navigate` call?

Comment: @tkone Not sure about `.navigate`, but the event fires after the route when loading a page.

Comment: Hmm.  I would love to be able to verify a user is authenticated before showing them the page they're getting to, but the method would have to be called prior to running the method associated with the route

Comment: @tkone there is a lack of before events in callbacks as of last I checked, though you can hack your way around it: http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/06/08/backbone-tips-after-and-before-methods-for-router/ . That being said, it wouldn't probably be considered good practice to check for authentication on the client-side.

Answer (score 9):

A more (new) Backbone way of writing the bind is:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this, "all", this.change )
},
```

a better listen would be just `route` if you ask me; Because `all` triggers two events, i think these:

> **"route:[name]"** (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is
>   matched.
>   **"route"** (route, params) — Fired by the router when any route
>   has been matched.

Comment: this is the better answer as of 2015

Comment: And it was made in 2014 :)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to backbone. Following Laurens answer, I managed to call on each route change with below

```
app_router.on('route', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```